# rails - how to show and save a date in us format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I can get my `content_date` to show in mm/dd/yyyy format and I can save it correctly.
If I have a validation error in other data the form redisplays the date the desired way which is `mm/dd/yyyy`
I can also edit a record and see the date in format mm/dd/yy

The problem I have is that editing the record flips the month and year so that

```
08/02/2012
```

becomes

```
02/08/2012
```

and

```
08/19/2012
```

doesn't work at all.

Ironically If I record the record twice in a row and the day is not more than 12 it flips back to the original value

View:

```
= f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10
```

I got new and create to work with (`links` controller)

```
def new
  @link = Link.new
  @link.content_date=Time.new().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  ...

def edit
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.content_date=Time.new().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if @link.content_date.nil?

def create
  @link = Link.new(link_params)

  if @link.content_date.nil?
    @link.content_date = Time.new().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
  else
    @link.content_date = @link.content_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
  end
```

but `update` (`rails 4.0.2`) is now just

```
def update
  redirect_to Link.find(params[:id]).tap { |link|
    link.update!(link_params)
  }
end
```

and I can't figure out how to change the `:content_date` in the update the way I did in the create

fyi I have the `american_date` gem in my `Gemfile` but it doesn't help (and doesn't help if I remove it either).

I don't currently have any date initializer in `config/initializers/`

js date picker:

```
$ cat app/assets/javascripts/date-picker.js 

$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
$(function(){
var dateInput = $("#datepicker");
var format = 'yy-mm-dd';
dateInput.datepicker({dateFormat: format});
dateInput.datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate(format, dateInput.val()));
});
```

Comment: Are you using a custom datepicker?

Comment: My guess would be the datepicker causing the problem. What datepicker are you using? Do things work normally if you remove the datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
/app/assets/javascripts/datepicker.js
```

changing

```
var format = 'yy-mm-dd';

to

var format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
```

Then I added a file `config/inititlaizers/date-format.js`, with

```
# Date
# ----------------------------
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"

# DateTime
# ----------------------------
DateTime::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"

# Time
# ----------------------------
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

This helped in all the displays and input fields and date-picker but the date still flipped.

Finally (this bit fixes the date flipping part), I changed my controller to be:

```
def update

  r = Link.find(params[:id])
  r.tap { |link|
    link.update!(link_params)
  } 
  r.update!(:content_date => link_params[:content_date].to_date.strftime("%Y-%d-%m"))
  redirect_to r

  end
```

Comment: The same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286467/how-can-i-use-us-style-dates-in-rails-using-ruby-1-9).  The answer boiled down to modifying the jQuery datepicker format, the Date/Time default format, and using the [ruby-american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date/blob/master/lib/american_date.rb) gem.  The gem essentially modifies the Ruby Date._parse method.  This means you don't have to write workaround code to persist every date field in your app.